# In Gradle KotlinScript DSL, how to import generated class accessors like `implementation`?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-dependencies

Assuming that a Gradle kt file under `<root>/buildSrc` requires a class accessor:

```
/**
 * Adds a dependency to the 'implementation' configuration.
 *
 * @param dependencyNotation notation for the dependency to be added.
 * @return The dependency.
 *
 * @see [DependencyHandler.add]
 */
fun DependencyHandler.`implementation`(dependencyNotation: Any): Dependency? =
    add("implementation", dependencyNotation)
```

Unfortunately, the entire file that defines this accessor is generated, so if I copy the function directly into my kt file it will be imported like this:

```
import gradle.kotlin.dsl.accessors._46b0ca6400a65b9754358ead47fee5d2.implementation
```

The `_46b0ca6400a65b9754358ead47fee5d2` will change every time the project is recompiled, so it is useless.

How could I import it reliably when the project is compiled anytime, anywhere?

(BTW the following solution was generated by an LLM, but it is equally useless and is clearly a result of hallucination):

```
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginExtension
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.dependencies
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.get
```